# How to ask a SELECT * from table where all columns that = $var

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

hi how to select columns that have the var value?
like this:

```
 $var=$_GET['id'];
 $select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE **COLUMNS THAT EQUAL TO VAR** = $var";
```

How to select those columns that have the $var value?

Clarification: SELECT only the columns that have the value $var in them.
Example:

```
$var="1";
```

Column 1, 7, 11 have on some row value 1 then pick those columns and show in which columns the value 1 is in

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

Comment: Do `WHERE col1="$var" OR col2="$var" OR ...` (and escape your inputs, to avoid a SQL injection). Note that if you have many columns doing the same thing, it is possible you should normalise your database. What is your table structure?

Comment: are you asking where col_name is $var or where col value is $var? This is different

Comment: you cannot "select columns". explain what you want. preferably with an example (this is the data set, and this is what I want to retrieve)

Comment: @halfer But OR only selects one column or more example if $var where to be in col1 and col2 and col3 but example not col4 but in col5 like in the edited question above

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no idea what you mean.

Comment: (Your questions will fare better here if you are on hand to immediately respond to questions in the comments, rather than an hour later, when the post has had the opportunity to acquire answers that misunderstand the question, downvotes and closevotes).

Comment: Sorry About that Im only human Im no machine ^^ Um I still haven't found the answer ^^ See the Picture I added lets say Id want to set the $var to equal to 3 so Id want to select only column 1 ,6 and 7 and tell those 3 columns have the number 3 .. is this possible and how?

Comment: The picture doesn't help, unfortunately. However your latest comment gives me a clue - you want to return `column1` if it is equal to 3, `column1, column2` if they are equal to three, `column1, column4, column7` if they are equal to three, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: If so, you need PHP. Use the `WHERE` clause I gave yesterday, and then `SELECT *` (i.e. all columns). You can then remove the columns that are not 3, from the resultset array, using PHP.

Comment: Um thanks this is the answer Ive looked for !

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention your column name in your query

If you want to check exact match you can do as follows

```
 $var=$_GET['id'];
  $select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = '$var'";
```

If you want to check column that contain @var you can do as follows

```
 $var=$_GET['id'];
  $select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name like '%$var%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You must look into **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** Database
Provide your database name => `$db`
Provide your column name   => `$column`
Then :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" . $db . "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" . $column . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

The query will look like this:

```
$var=$_GET['id'];
// for checking if both the column name and value are the same $var value 
$select= "SELECT ".$var." FROM table_name WHERE ".$var."='".$var."'"
```

OR

```
$var = $_GET['id'];
// for checking if both the column name and value are different
$select= = "SELECT ".$var." FROM table_name WHERE ".$var."='".$otherValue."'"
```

Between this is **SQLinjection vulnerable code**. You should check the variables before using them in query. Also you should start using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

The easy ways is to use php to get array from all columns:

```
SELECT column_name FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = 'YOUR-DB-NAME' and TABLE_NAME='YOUR-TABLE-NAME'
```

And use 'for' to create 'where' 
for example:

```
for($i=0;$colums[$i];$i++) $where.=" or {$colums[$i]} like '%string%'";
$SQL="Select * from table where 1=1 $where";
```